# Is is possible that three countries have three points in common?

Tags: graph-theory

On the world map, there are several instances of three countries that have two points in common. For example, China, Russia and Mongolia.

Is there any arrangement of three (fictional) countries such that they have three points in common? For the question, we'll assume that every country exists just of one piece.

I think it isn't possible. If we consider the capitals of each of the country, and the three points they have in common, and we connect each capital to each point they have in common, we get $K_{3,3}$, which is not planar. However, I do not see how this shows that it is not possible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Very interesting, but note that for this question we'll assume that every country exists just of one piece, as said in the question.

Comment: @wythagoras: But the Lakes of Wada each consist of one piece, don't they?

Comment: Yes, my bad. It didn't look like that on the picture.